# Salesforce Classic Report View - remove edit link from Field Filters

Tags: reporting, permissions, reports-folder

**Background**

Hi, I have a problem with removing Edit link from Report View as presented below:

[image: Report View]

Profile permissions activated:

- Run Report permission
- View Reports in Public Folders

checked with Folders:

- Unfiled Public Reports
- New Folder with sharing to specific User as a Viewer and with another user set as manager.

**Problem**
Can't hide Edit link from report View.
Login as folder manager doesn't seems to have manager access level, Viewer have same options as manager (which looks like profile permissions) but still folder share as Viewer (with Manager set) should hide Edit link?  Or is there any other option which i may miss?

Comment: Can you elaborate more what is your expectation when you login as Manager?
Do u want to edit the report for Manager?

Comment: Thanks for reply. What i want is report shared as read only with **Filter by**  Edit link hided.

Comment: By using manager i just make this folder private. both users Manager and Viewer have same profile but still i cannot turn off filtered by Edit link

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can not hide report filter criteria from Reports.Check the below link:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000a2j8AAA

You can vote the idea on the above link.Who knows when salesforce will deliver it :)

Comment: Hide would be best but as long it's not possible is there any way to hide **edit link** for Report View? It should be possible but i can't find solution :|

Comment: My Suggestion would be Use a VF page and somehow hide the frame with the filters.You can check the below link that will guide you to display reports within VF Page:


https://vanityforce.wordpress.com/2011/10/10/displaying-a-report-within-visualforce/

But honestly speaking I am not sure if it is possible as I have never tried this before..